# Batch File moving files by date with Looping

Tags: loops, batch-file

we are trying to use a batch file to move documents into specific sub-directories.  The files all start with a date format:  mmddyyyy_filename.  Our folder structure is like this:  c:\client\user\year\month.  Files are all downloaded into the c:\client\user directory.  From there we have to sort files into the corresponding year, and then into the corresponding months.  Some of these directories will have 10000+ files so doing it by hand is extremely time consuming.  We have created a batch file that allows us to set a variable for the client, user, year and month, but we would like to loop through the month and year if possible automatically.  The current batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off

:client
set /p client= Which client?

:Provider
set /p provider= Which provider (First initial, last name)?
/k if %provider% == clean GOTO Cleanup
/k if %provider% == x GOTO client
/k if %provider% == *. * GOTO Year

:Year
set /p year= Which year (4 digit year)?
if %year% neq 2019 GOTO Month
if %year% == 2019 GOTO provider

:Month
set /p month= Which month (2 digit number)?
if %month% neq 13 GOTO Command
if %month% == 13 GOTO Year

:Command
E:
cd E:\Backups\"%client%"\"%Provider%"\
move %month%??%year%_* E:\Backups\"%client%"\"%Provider%"\%year%\%month%
GOTO Month

:Cleanup
ROBOCOPY "E:\Backups\%client%" "E:\Backups\%client%" /S /MOVE
GOTO client
```

Rather than typing in months individually, 01, 02, 03, etc... we would like it to loop through each of these months without any user input.  Ideally it would loop through years 2007-2018 as well.  Currently when we type month 13, it will return us to Year prompt, when we type 2019 it will return us to the provider prompt.

Any help accomplishing this would be great!

Comment: One piece of advise: first do your `Robocopy` using the `/L` switch : it will show you everything it wants to do, you can then check if everything is ok, and only then remove the `/L` from your `Robocopy` and you'll be sure that all your copy commands are correct.

Comment: I have tested the Robocopy command and it does function as we are hoping.  Thank you though.

Comment: Either use [for /L](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loops or [disassemble](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) the file name.

Comment: I have tried using the for /L loop, but I can't get it to advance past the first month, it just loops 01 over and over:

:loop
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 13) do (
call :Command
set "month=0%%i"
!month:~-2!
)

Comment: if you do `set` and use it in a code block you need to `enabledelayedexpansion` see `set /?`

Comment: We decided to just re-write the code the long way.  It is for a singular purpose of backing up files so it doesn't need adjusted after working.  We just used:

Set year=2008
Set month=01
Move %month%??%year% “c:\%client%\%provider%\%year%\%month%\
Set month=02
Move %month%??%year% “c:\%client%\%provider%\%year%\%month%\
Set month=03
Move %month%??%year% “c:\%client%\%provider%\%year%\%month%\

Etc

Comment: What's the `/k` prefix in the `:Provider` section? typos just in this post? N. B.: The date format `mmddyyyy` is not quite good for sorting; consider to change it to `yyyymmdd`, if possible; if these dates just reflect the last modification dates of the files anyway, you could use this for sorting/filtering though...

Comment: For the months, you could use a standard `for` loop rather than `for /L` just to avoid having to add the leading zero, like this: `for %%M in (01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12) do (...)`

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not work as expected because your examples are not complete, but it is to demonstrate what you pretty much requested.

It will prompt for a task (which ever tasks you want to perform) where I used `move` and `clean` as examples. The ask provider and client. The loop will do each year and each  month of that year, you can add/remove as you want.

```
@echo off
set "mm=01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12"
set "yyyy=2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019"
set /p "task=enter task (clean, move): "
set /p "client=Which client?: "
set /p "provider= Which Provider? (Initial, Lastname): "
if "%task%"=="clean" (
     echo robocopy "E:\Backups\%client%" "E:\Backups\%client%" /S /MOVE
  )
)
if /i "%task%"=="move" (
for %%a in (%yyyy%) do for %%i in (%mm%) do (
      echo mkdir "E:\Backups\%client%\%provider%\%%a\%%i" 2>nul
      echo move %%i??%%a_* "E:\Backups\%client%\%provider%\%%a\%%i"
  )
)
```

**Note!!** the above will simply `echo` the commands inside the loop as a safery feature, removing `echo` commands will perform the actual tasks.